# Why toolbox in Visual Studio 2017 xamarin project is empty

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xamarin, toolbox

I want to write a program in xamarin c#.net by Visual Studio 2017 
So I new a xamarin project and when I want to drag and drop controls into xaml form but I noticed that  there is no control in toolbox panel. How to solve this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/installation/windows

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is the case just as you said: before the preview gets focused, the Toolbox is empty as follows

[image]

But you can try the following steps to make it display:

1 To make the preview focused, you can simply click it.

[image]

2 When the preview get focused, the Toolbox will display.

[image]

Hope it can help you.